# Memory Game javascript Reset function only working for the last two clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I'm doing a memory game, but I can't seem to figure out the solution to reset the card.  For now I have written a small code which will only turn the last two cards that were clicked in the game, but I want all the cards to turn when the reset `button` is clicked .

Here is the code below :

```
const resetbtn = document.querySelectorAll('.restart');

function resetcard(){

  if(cards[firstclick] == cards[secondclick]){
    firstclick.classList.remove('open','show','match');
    secondclick.classList.remove('open','show','match');
  }

}

resetbtn.forEach(resetbt => resetbt.addEventListener('click',resetcard));
```

The project link is **[here](https://codepen.io/DLAbeykoon/pen/MWWrqMG)**.

Comment: what is the content of `cards` ...since `firstclick` and `secondclick` seem to be DOM elements, I can't see how `cards[firstclick]` could be a thing - perhaps you need to shown what all these things are

Comment: i have added the project link

Comment: that's good ... so, what are `cards`, `firstclick` and `secondclick`?

Comment: check the javascript code cards is the variable for classname card which is the list of  tiles in the game and you have to click on the two tiles/ cards to match them that is known taken as the first and second click check the javascript if you can please

Comment: *check the javascript code* - the javascript code in the question doesn't show anything

Comment: @NAND You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and not any third party site.

Comment: "cards.reload" isn't a function - and why would it be

Comment: oh sorry that was a mistake i edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code fixes all stated and unstated issues, including

- shuffling
- can't select the same first card in two attempts

Hope this helps

```
/*
 * Create a list that holds all of your cards
 */
const cards = [...document.querySelectorAll('.card')];
const carddeck = document.querySelector('.deck');

let hasturnedcard = false;
let firstclick, secondclick;
//letting the board pause a little long until the cards and turned fully
let pauseboard = false;

function turncard() {
    if (pauseboard)
        return; //pause the board from turning tiles more than two tiles

    // if the card contains show it's either already selected as the first selection, or is a match - either way ignore clicks
    if (this.classList.contains('show')) {
        return;
    }

    this.classList.add('open', 'show');

    if (!hasturnedcard) {
        hasturnedcard = true;
        firstclick = this;

    } else {
        hasturnedcard = false;
        secondclick = this;
        matchingtiles();
    }
}
// the created to see whether the tiles are matching
function matchingtiles() {
    if (firstclick.dataset.name === secondclick.dataset.name) {
        //its a match
        firstclick.classList.add('match');
        secondclick.classList.add('match');
        // no need to remove click handler, since we handle logic in the click handler, and on reset we'd just add the click handler again anyway!
    } else {
        //not a match
        tilesturning();
    }
}

// if the tiles are not a match after the click function a timeout is added to slow the process of tiles turning back again
function tilesturning() {
    pauseboard = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        //delaying the turning process
        firstclick.classList.remove('open', 'show');
        secondclick.classList.remove('open', 'show');
        firstclick = secondclick = null;
        pauseboard = false;
    }, 1000);
}
cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', turncard));
// reset the card of tiles after clicking on the reset button
document.querySelector('.restart').addEventListener('click', () => {
    shuffle(cards);
    cards.forEach(card => {
        card.classList.remove('open', 'show', 'match');
        carddeck.appendChild(card);
    });
});

function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue,
    randomIndex;
    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: RIP Quag :( Stay cool, he's worth more to us alive than dead...

Comment: I'm sorry @CertainPerformance, not sure how that relates to a 2 year old, accepted, and may I say brilliant answer :p

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are accessing cards map with HTML elements as Keys, you should use unique strings, for example you could use Element id like `cards[firstClick.id]`.

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question or only a comment on his code?

Comment: @rob He has Problems because he access maps with HTML elements as keys, and this give him the unexpected behaviour. Fixing it the Code should works correctly.